# Leading Zeros getting truncated using SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, db2, substr

One of the values in the column is
`089-002007`

I wish to extract all the numbers after '-'

```
SELECT SUBSTR(EMP_NO,5)
FROM Table_Name
```

However, I get the output as '2007', the leading zeros got truncated. I have multiple values where it starts with 0 after the '-'.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's implicitly changing the result to int, hence chopping off leading zeroes.  I would suggest CAST-ing the SELECT

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(EMP_NO,5) AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform and version of DB2?

You should be getting '002007' back given the code you've shown.

The output of `SUBSTR()` is already varchar.

The DBMS wouldn't change it from varchar to int, unless you've tried to treat it like an int.

```
select substr('089-002007',5)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Returns

```
SUBSTR
002007
```

On the other hand,

```
select substr('089-002007',5) + 0
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Returns

```
Numeric Expression
           2,007
```